# Trouble with distributing space between diagonal rows

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, shapes, patterns, spacing

I'm trying to space out these diagonal rows evenly, but I have failed to accomplish this, since they seem to take random positions every time I use either Horizontal Distribute Space or Horizontal Distribute Center. Below is an image of what I want evenly spaced.

[image: Before]

...and below is my issue, and what keeps happening when I either use Horizontal Distribute Space or Horizontal Distribute Center.

[image: After]

I know that I've been able to do this before with success, but I can't seem to figure out, where the issue is now. Each row is grouped individually with the elements in that row, and I have chosen that it should align to section as well.

Comment: Have you tried Distribute *Spacing*?

Comment: Rotate so that they are euther horisontal or vertical, then space them. And rotate back.